# Confusion with query of count

Tags: mysql

I have a ticket management system in my site. A table named tkt_container in record all responses with 2 columns name ticket id and user id

```
TICKET ID | USER ID
101       | A
105       | B
103       | A
110       | A
105       | A
101       | A
103       | A
101       | A
```

Other table dept_info stores ticket info like this.

```
Dept Name | Ticket ID
Billing   | 101
Billing   | 110
Accounts  | 105
CustomerSu| 103
```

Now I wish to fetch in this way like department name and total responses..

```
DEpt Name | Total responses for A
Billing   | 4
Accounts  | 2
CustomerSu| 2
```

Comment: though I tried with Inner query but that was not satisfying my needs so removed it..

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `Dept Name`, COUNT(`USER ID`)
FROM dept_info
LEFT JOIN tkt_container ON tkt_container.`TICKET ID` = dept_info.`Ticket ID`
GROUP BY dept_info.`Dept Name`
```

I **STRONGLY** urge you to pick better names for your fields and tables. There's absolutely no valid reason for putting spaces into a field name.

Comment: I have already done that but missed the way to represent in correct way here.

Answer (score 0):

Use a query like this (I wrote it for user 'A'):

```
select di.dept_name, count(*) as 'Total responses for A'
from  dept_info di inner join tkt_container tc on di.ticket_id = tc.ticket_id
where tc.user_id = 'A'
group by di.dept_name
order by di.dept_name
```